# Codeigniter designing without objects

Tags: php, codeigniter

Seems codeigniter only allows one instance of a library I can't design a solution with objects holding arrays of corresponding details as I usually would. I'm considering just doing AJAX calls to make additional queries from the view to fill the would be objects with their corresponding details. Does anyone  have ideas for a more elegant solution?

Comment: Can you clarify ? What do you mean only one instance of a library ?

Comment: And what does it mean `make additional queries from the view to fill the would be objects` ?

Comment: @Damien Pirsy What do you think? :P

Comment: I don't know, the sentence makes little sense, care to explain or to clarify your intentions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there is so a way to call an object more than once:

```
$this->load->library('someclass', $params, 'alc');
```

the CodeIgniter User Guide explains that very well. the third parameter alc will be what you now use to call that object injunction with the other, I have to do this myself a few times.

i wouldn't do the require route as CI does a nice job of handling all those objects calls on its own.

Answer (score 0):

You can still instantiate multiple objects just not through the codeigniter $this super class. You can simply include the libray file you need manually using `require()` or `include()` for example and use $object = new MyClass();

You can then pass any objects you make to the view using `$this->load->view('viewname', array('object', $object ));` but beware objects (class variables) are converted to array elements when passed to the view in this way. So you can still manipulate them as objects before passing to the view as you would in any other application.